# 2003 Toyota Rav4: Scratching sound above 4k RPM

Tags: toyota, noise, transmission, manual-transmission, rav4

I have a manual transmission, 2003 Toyota Rav4. The problem is that there is now a scratching sound, originating from the front center (sounds like it is right behind the front air vents), that starts at ~4k RPM and grows louder/faster as the RPM increases.

The problem is similar to the one described here:
[Drivetrain sounds like rustling leaves above 4k RPMs](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/23917/drivetrain-sounds-like-rustling-leaves-above-4k-rpms)

The difference is that the noise occurs whether a gear is engaged or is in neutral. This is a link to a video with audio of the noise:
[Rav4 Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GpJfqEgF10z3yxKtiS1HUoWENF3aGI3E/)

Though different than the other StackExchange question, I wonder if the answer would be the same, a loose bearing or other.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I watched the video and can just *barely* make out the sound which I believe you're talking about. No clue as to what it might be, though.

Comment: @Paulster2 thank you. It isn't too loud a sound, but it is consistent. If it isn't a sign of a larger issue, it wouldn't bother me.